# Auto-complete implementation with Mongo DB and Full-text Index

Tags: mongodb, text, indexing, autocomplete, full-text-search

We currently have a problem that involves populating a specific auto-complete dropdown with results from a mongo database.

The mongo entity sort of looks like this:

```
db.testscore.insert({
    name: "demolition",
    alias: ["explosion", "detonation"],
    frontPartialName: ["demolitio", "demoliti", "demolit", "demoli", "demol", "demo", "dem"],
    frontPartialAlias: [ "explosio", "explosi", "explos", "explo", "expl", "exp", "detonatio", "detonati", "detonat", "detona",...<insert more data here>...det],
    partialName: ["emo", "mol", "oli"....<insert more data here>..."emolition", "molition"],
    partialAlias: ["xpl", "plos"...<insert more data here>...,"eton", "toni"]
});
```

**VERY IMPORTANT: The backend should return the following results in the following order (if they exist)**

1. entity with exact match to the "name" field
2. entity with any match to the "alias" field
3. entity that partially matches the first few letters of the "name" field
4. entity that partially matches the first few letters of any of the "alias" field
5. entity that partially matches the partial substring of the "name" field
6. entity that partially matches the partial substring of any of the "alias" field

**What we did:**

1.) created a text index:

```
db.testscore.ensureIndex({
    name: "text",
    alias: "text",
    frontPartialName: "text",
    frontPartialAlias: "text",
    partialName: "text",
    partialAlias: "text"
}, {
    weights: {
        name: 243,
        alias: 81,
        frontPartialName: 27,
        frontPartialAlias: 9,
        partialName: 3,
        partialAlias: 1
    },
    name: "searchIndex"
});
```

2.) perform a text search using the users input and sorted it by score

```
db.testscore.find({
    $text: {
        $search: "<insert input here>"
    }
}, {
    score: { $meta: "textScore"},
    originalName: 1,
    originalAlias: 1
}).sort({
    score: { $meta: "textScore"}
});
```

Is there any better way to solve this kind of issue? Our database currently contains 5 million records and is expected to grow,
the index is consuming too much space and will hardly fit the memory. Ive read that mongo relies on that to search faster (otherwise some paging will happen).

If we cant do this with mongo, we might end up with using a proper full-text database.

Comment: Why would you break down all of those tokens and then use a text search? I'd almost say two `$regex` in an `$or` over the field two fields should be enough. But you would not be able to get a rank on where it was matched since the aggregation framework ( next logical choice ) cannot do "logical" matches on regular expressions. I'd be pretty sure that most of your "tokens" are being ignored by `$text` in the first place. This might be a bit out of scope for the basic text search facilities in MongoDB

Comment: the ordering is the most important thing. and regex is ridiculously slow.

Comment: Not if it's anchored `^`. Anyway I ruled it out because of the scoring. As I did say, chances are most of the content in the arrays is being ignored in the indexing anyway, since they are in fact "partial words".

Comment: i tot i could fool stemming into thinking that these are actual words. for example inserting a {name:"x"} would index that to "x". i must have misread the docs. thanks for the info

Comment: @BlakesSeven you are wrong about tokens being ignored. even if they are not real words, mongo is still returning them on the query. i just tried inserting giberrish stuffs and they were considered by mongo.